# how to config rsync as deamon when a file change and not with cron

Tags: rsync

I have multiple folders that I rsync now with cron like in this example.

```
rsync -aqz source1/  user1@machine1:/some/destination1
rsync -aqz source2/  user2@machine2:/some/destination2
... and so on
```

Everything is running fine, but I have a lot of crontabs as root, and most of the time nothing changes, and I am just blocking processor.

I would like to start the rsync processes only when a file somewhere on source has changed.

So I have read the documentation of the rsync.conf file, but I did not understand how this works.
My rsync.conf file right now looks like this :

```
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid

&merge /etc/rsyncd.d
&include /etc/rsyncd.d
```

and the /etc/rsyncd.d folder is empty.

how do I need to write the config in order that the rsync runs as daemon and just syncs when a file has changed.

Comment: What do you mean by files on source have been changed ?

Comment: I don't know how to say it with other words.